# Number of table count is wrong in dataset

Tags: powershell, dataset

I am supplying 3 servers to loop however the `$mdtable.table.count` is only 1. I must be missing a simple thing here. Can anyone please help me resolve this?

```
Get-Content 'C:\test\computers.txt' | ? { $_.Trim() -ne "" } | ForEach-Object {
  $value = Invoke-Command -Computer $_ -ScriptBlock {
    Param($computer)
    # Connect to SQL and query data, extract data to SQL Adapter
    $SqlQuery = "xp_fixeddrives"
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$computer;Initial Catalog='Secaudit';Integrated Security = True";
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($SqlQuery, $Sqlconnection)
    $mdtable = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
    $nRecs = $SqlAdapter.Fill($mdtable) | Out-Null
    $nRecs | Out-Null
    $res = $mdtable.Tables.Count
    $res
  } -ArgumentList $_ -Credential $cred
}
$value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you're missing is that

```
... | ForEach-object {
  $value = Invoke-Command -Computer $_ -ScriptBlock {
    ...
  } -ArgumentList $_ -Credential $cred 
}
```

*replaces* the value of `$value` with each iteration when you actually want to *accumulate* the values.

You can achieve this for instance like this:

```
... | ForEach-object {
  $value += Invoke-Command -Computer $_ -ScriptBlock {
    ...
  } -ArgumentList $_ -Credential $cred 
}
```

or like this:

```
$value = ... | ForEach-object {
  Invoke-Command -Computer $_ -ScriptBlock {
    ...
  } -ArgumentList $_ -Credential $cred 
} | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -Expand Sum
```

Comment: i used $value += and for the last server mentioned in the text file its giving me the result twice

Comment: Very unlikely. Please provide evidence.

Comment: i used $value += as you suggested and for the last server mentioned in the text file, its giving me the duplicate results when we see the output of the variable $value, however the count is correct and for the second option its giving me an error "Measure-Object : Input object "" is not numeric."

Comment: may be the issue is not related to this, i will open another thread for this. Thanks a lot :)